# Java array filled with what is in the last slot

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So i'm using this for loop to fill a small array with 5 random things from a larger array but i have a problem where when i fill the original array with this new object it fills every slot above it with the object that was just put in. so everything in my smaller array is the same as well.

```
`public Prize[] Showcase(){

        Scanner fileIn=null;
        try{
            fileIn = new Scanner(new File("prizeList.txt"));    
            for(int i=0;fileIn.hasNextLine();i++){
                String delim ="\t";
                String[] splitStrings=fileIn.nextLine().split(delim);
                if(splitStrings.length==2){
                    int thing = Integer.parseInt(splitStrings[1]);
                    prizeList[i]=new Prize(splitStrings[0],thing);


                }

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);              
        }
        return prizeList;

    }
    public static void Prizes(Prize[] prizeList){
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        Random bkRandy=new Random();
        int randy = bkRandy.nextInt(50);
        prizes[i]=prizeList[i];
        System.out.println(prizes[i].getName());
        }
    }`
```

i'm not sure what's going on i've never seen it do anything like this. I dont get any errors or anything there is just something wrong with the loop i suspect.

My question is "why is it filling every slot with the last object?"

```
public class Prize {
    private static String name;
    private static int price;
    public Prize( String name, int price){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public static int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public static String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Don't know about your issue, but this doesn't look right... `for(int i=0;fileIn.hasNextLine();i++){`

Comment: Its the same thing as using a while(fileIn.hasNextLine()) and putting a counter in.

Comment: How do you ensure `i` doesn't get incremented past the size of the `prizeList` array? Also - you're creating a new `Random` object each time through the loop - you want one object created outside the loop. That might be related to your question...

Comment: also, where are prizeList and prizes declared...? are they class variables somewhere? if so, it's probably not a good idea to make the argument of Prizes() also called prizeList

Comment: you got me there. I just know the line number of the file i'm scanning. Thanks for that, i'll change it. Obviously i'm somewhat new so I usually mess around until something works and fix it when problems arise.

Comment: yeah they are class variables. i see what you're saying i changed that too. thank you.

Comment: In Prizes(), are you trying to assign a random element from prizeList to prizes - as in `prizes[i] = prizeList[randy]`? and what do you mean by "it fills every slot above it with the object that was just put in"?

Comment: Still however it doesn't fill up the Array properly.

Comment: so like when it scans a new line of the file i'm reading it and makes that a new "Prize" and puts it in the array. but when it scans the next line it does that same thing but overwriting all the previous slots in the array with what was just put in the next slot.  And correct i am trying to assign a random value from prizeList to prizes.

Comment: Show us `Prize`, the constructor and the fields. My *guess* is that you've made the fields `static`.

Comment: sorry i had a little trouble editing it in correct format. Prize itself is pretty bare though.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch looks like you're correct (!) basically, the name and price fields shouldn't be static, as that indicates that those fields are shared across each instance, rather than having a separate field for each instance.

Comment: Yeah when he asked to look at it i began messing around with the static thing but i am unsure how to properly use it while it is not static. i keep getting a null point exception when i call a get method.

Comment: just remove static from the class variables (name, price) and their getters (getName, getPrice) and it should work

Comment: it gives me an error on this line              System.out.println(prizes[i].getName());

Comment: Thanks guys! I figured it out right before i needed to turn it in. I'm horrible at calling things statically but i think i finally figured it out. This was a very good lesson.

Comment: @gengkev Experience. And when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Not so improbable, really, but I just didn't think of that. I guess I learned something, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make something `static` there is only one. Your instances are therefore unique references that share the same data. You need something like

```
public class Prize {
    private String name;  // <-- not static.
    private int price;  // <-- not static.
    public Prize(String name, int price){
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public int getPrice() {  // <-- not static.
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getName() { // <-- not static.
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
}
```

With your `Prize` code, you would only get the "last" value because every instance shared the class level fields (`static`).

Comment: Do you now understand what `static` does?

Comment: I understand it now. It basically just makes it the same thing overall so when i changed it it had to change all of them to whatever i just changed it to.

Comment: It's a class-level global; one per class (not one per instance). When you changed "it" *it was the **only** one*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to get a list of random items from another list. I'm assuming you specifically don't want duplicates (i.e. the short list should not contain more than one item from the longer list). If that's correct then I would suggest the following:

```
List<Prize> getRandomPrizes(List<Prize> prizes, int prizeCount) {
    Collections.shuffle(prizes);
    return prizes.stream().limit(prizeCount).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

That automatically copes with the situation in which there are less than `prizeCount` prizes in the original list.

Comment: I can't use array lists for this program. otherwise it would have made things tons easier.